# KafkaMessageListenerContainer how to do nack for specific error

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` with (`KafkaAdapter`).

How can I "nack" offsets in case of specific error, so the next `poll()` will take them again?

```
properties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);

final KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory , properties);



kafkaContainer.setCommonErrorHandler(new CommonErrorHandler() {
     

  @Override
  public void handleBatch(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecords<?, ?> data, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, Runnable invokeListener) {
         CommonErrorHandler.super.handleBatch(thrownException, data, consumer, container, invokeListener);
   }

});
```

Inside `handleBatch` I am detecting the exception, for that specific exception I would like to do nack.
Tried to throw from there RuntimeException.

using springboot 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DefaultErrorHandler` - it does exactly that (the whole batch is retried according to the back off). You can classify which exceptions are retryable or not.

If you throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` you can specify exactly which record in the batch had the failure and only retry it (and the following records).

**EDIT**

If any other type of exception is thrown, the DefaultErrorHandler falls back to using a FallbackBatchErrorHandler which calls ErrorHandlingUtils.retryBatch() which, pauses the consumer and redelivers the whole batch without seeking and re-polling (the polls within the loop return no records because the consumer is paused).

See the documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh

This is required, because there is no guarantee that the batch will be fetched in the same order after a seek.

This is because we need to know the state of the batch (how many times we have retried). We can't do that if the batch keeps changing; hence the algorithm I described above.

To retry indefinitely you can, for example, use a `FixedBackOff` with `Long.MAX_VALUE` in the `maxAttempts` property. Or use an `ExponentialBackOff` with no termination.

Just be sure that the largest back off (and time to process a batch) is significantly less than `max.poll.interval.ms` to avoid a rebalance.

Comment: Do I need to override any method?
as I tired  as  `kafkaContainer.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler())` it did 9 attmpts, and that it. I expected next poll() to repeat it. 
`BatchListenerExecutionFailedException' can't find that class.

Comment: You can set a custom back off; the default is 9 retries with no backoff between them. Sorry, it's just `BatchListenerFailedException`.

Comment: I am still missing something as poll() is not re triggered  - I expect it to enter a loop. records polled -> exception -> offsets not committed/message returned -> following poll brings the records again.

Comment: If any other type of exception is thrown, the DefaultErrorHandler falls back to using a `FallbackBatchErrorHandler` which calls `ErrorHandlingUtils.retryBatch()` which, pauses the consumer and resends the whole batch without seeking and re-polling (the polls within the loop return no records because the consumer is paused). See the documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh This is required, because there is no guarantee that the batch will be fetched in the same order after a seek.

Comment: Note that `AckMode.BATCH` has nothing to do with processing as a batch; it just defines how often offsets are committed. Processing as a batch (rather than single records) requires `batchListener=true` and a method signature that receives a `List<?>`.

Comment: For a record listener, the `handleOne` method is called, which re-seeks the current record (up to the retries) and re-polls from that point.

Comment: yes, I Have `List<>` in signature and  `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch`. I am explicitly throwing exception, `ErrorHandlingUtils.retryBatch` is called, while loop iterates, and then exits. So If I want to run until error is fixed, I must set BackOff to run forever?

Comment: I thought I could just "reset" offsets so poll() would act as nothing happened. Also I don't care about order. whole batch should be retried.

Comment: No; we can't do that because we need to know the state of the batch (how many times we have retried). We can't do that if the batch keeps changing; hence the algorithm I described above. With a record listener, we do indeed commit the previous offsets, re-seek the remaining partitions and poll again; we just can't do that with a batch listener.

Comment: Yes; to run forever, you would need an infinite back off.

Comment: interesting, nice to learn. can you update the answer with last remarks, for other people to see and I will accept the answer. thank you as always.

Comment: last question, if I retry forever(and after some time recover) I won't get rebalance, correct?

Comment: Right, because we pause the consumer and poll between retries; you just need to be sure that any individual back off interval (and the time taken to process the batch)  is less than `max.poll.interval.ms` (with some generous margin), to avoid a rebalance. I will add the above comments to the answer. Note that this technique also avoids any unnecessary re-fetching from the broker.

Comment: if I set `DefaultErrorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(SomeMyException.class);`  and then in the flow I throw that Exception, I still see that `DefaultErrorHandler handleBatch` is called.

Comment: What version are you using? That was a problem fixed in 2.8.11 and 2.9.3. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2459 The method will still be called, but the recoverer is called immediately.

Comment: 2.8.6, is it a problem? I can't upgrade.

Comment: You should always keep up to date with the latest bug fixe releases, even if you can't move up to the next minor version (2.9.x); it is fixed in 2.8.11 and later versions. 2.8.x is now out of OSS support. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

Comment: version dictated by the spring that I have... thanks  I will do some workaround

Comment: You can override the version that Boot pulls in, but you should really use the latest Boot 2.7 bug fix release - 2.7.8 https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn which pulls in SK 2.8.11.

Comment: thank you, using 2.7 :( will try to update kafka only and see

Comment: looks like `pause` is not really working I still get   partitions lost, partitions revoked, (Re-)joining group. (means rebalance still happens when retries time is  exceeding  `max.poll.interval.ms`)

Comment: I also verified `consumer.pause(assignment);`  was called

Comment: Of course; a rebalance will always occur if you exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: so what is the point of doing pause? How  can I still apply unlimited retry policy that we already discussed and to avoid rebalance?

Comment: Even when paused, the consumer must poll within the interval. Pausing simply means the poll becomes a no-op.

Comment: so there is no way to apply unlimited retires without rebalance?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: thanks, i just was confused by your previous comment `you just need to be sure that any individual back off interval (and the time taken to process the batch) is less than max.poll.interval.ms (with some generous margin), to avoid a rebalance.` - thought that each retry is considered individual back off interval

Comment: Yes; that is correct the consumer is polled between each retry; so any individual back off must be less than the interval. See `FallbackBatchErrorHandler` and `ErrorHandlerUtils.retryBatch()`. There was a recent change to poll again before re-invoking the listener; before that `each retry delay + time to process the batch` had to be less than the interval. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2543

Comment: hmmm, interesting, because my max retry delay is 60 seconds, time to process is 1 second (fails immediately ). `max.poll.interval.ms`is 5 min...

Comment: Then you shouldn't be seeing rebalances. If you can provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior, I can take a look to see what's wrong.